# Как правильно использовать предлоги "о" и "насчет"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно использовать предлоги **"о"** и **"насчет"**, когда по смыслу подходят оба?
Например, ***"поговорить насчет отпуска"*** или ***"поговорить об отпуске"***.
Если оба правильные, то какой вариант лучше выбрать? И почему?

Answer (score 2):

Из словаря: **О; ОБ; ОБО**, предлог. II. о ком-чём. 1. Употр. при обозначении лица, предмета, явления и т.п., которые представляют собой объект разговоров, размышлений, забот и т.п. Мечта о подвиге. Мысль о предстоящей работе.  Говорить о последних событиях. Рассказать о себе.

**НАСЧЁТ**, предлог. кого-чего. Разг. Относительно кого-, чего-л. Договориться н. статьи, поездки, отпуска, адвоката, врача. Осведомиться н. здоровья. Разговор н. аренды.

**Изъяснительный предлог О** ― **нейтральный, общего значения,** используется для названия предмета, о котором идет речь. Предлог НАСЧЁТ ― **разговорный, при этом обычно он кратко обозначает целевой аспект  разговора**: поговорить об отпуске (вообще), поговорить насчет отпуска (обсудить какие-то конкретные детали).

**Примеры** (для предлога НАСЧЕТ):

Я объяснил ему **насчёт** Интернета. Вот я **насчёт** этого как раз и хотел с тобой посоветоваться". Поэтому **насчёт** точности даты у меня оставались сильные сомнения.

Comment: Неудачный пример "объяснил насчёт Интернета". Ошибка в управлении.

Comment: Размышление нашло на меня; а размышлял я больше о премудрости: что вот, как, мол, это Прохорыч мне справедливо объяснил насчет предостереженья ― и почему это именно надо мной такие чудеса совершаются?.. [И. С. Тургенев. Собака (1847-1852)]. И тотчас он встал, попрощался, что-то путано объяснил насчет того, что опаздывает, и пошел поспешно к калитке, вовсе забыв про рекомендацию для «Молодого колхозника». [Ю. В. Трифонов. Время и место (1980)]. Тебе же Андрей сегодня объяснил насчет ученых. [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Град обреченный (1972)]